# How to remove the decimal part from a float number that contains .000 in RDLC

Tags: decimal, expression, reportviewer, rdlc, rounding

I have a RDLC, contains a column weight, to show a float number.
If there's any decimal part, I have to show it.
If there's no decimal part, I shouldn't show x.000000

What do you suggest to do so?

### Example

- the number is 10.000001 then, I have to show the exact number, 10.000001
- the number is 10.000000 then, I have to show 10
- the number is 10.001000 then, I have to show 10.001

how can I do this in an expression of RDLC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you already tried this -

```
=Format(Fields!<<Field>>.Value, "#.########")
```

"#" will display the value if present.

You can also try

```
=Format(Fields!<<Field>>.Value, "D")
```

Also check - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use conversion

```
 CDbl(Fields!<<Field>>.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
=FormatNumber(field,NoOfDigitsAfterDecimal)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt(v=vs.90).aspx